# Is there a difference between using a[i] and *(a + i)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Both `a[i]` and `*(a + i)` access the `i` th element of array `a`.

Are there reasons to prefer one over the other(*performance, readability, etc...*)?

Comment: You can even prefer `i[a]` on top of those two.

Comment: Whichever is most consistent with the style of the rest of your program.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Neither does yours or any other answer says anything else than `a[i] == *(a+i) == *(i+a) == i[a]` which is actually a FAQ here.  Besides, do you have evidence to support which variant _performs_ better than the other.

Comment: @devnull neither should perform better than the other, array indexing should just be syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic and as the standard says should be `identical`. If you have evidence otherwise then you should provide an answer that explains the performance difference. I would definitely like to see it but that would be a pretty factual answer wouldn't it?

Comment: It is silly to say this question is opinion based. There is valid and completely factual answer to this question. It is not obvious that one `should` have identical performance unless you go to the standard and see that they should be identical.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither one is better from a language point of view since they are the same, array indexing should just be syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. We can see this from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.2.1` *Array subscripting* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is **identical** to (*((E1)+(E2))).[..]

Although for others reading your code `a[i]` is probably more readable.

Answer (score 7):

Although they are identical in arrays, I prefer a[i] for the following reason. Suppose you have code like this:

```
double gradient[3];

// 200 lines later
double dx = gradient[0]; // Works fine
double dy = *(gradient + 1); // Works just as well
```

Then somebody decided that std::vector looks better than double[]:

```
vector<double> gradient;

// 200 lines later
double dx = gradient[0]; // Still works
double dy = *(gradient + 1); // Ouch!
```

Then somebody else decided to go object-oriented all the way:

```
class Gradient
{
public:
    double operator[](int index) const; 
};

// 1000 lines later
Gradient gradient;

// 200 lines later
double dx = gradient[0]; // Still works
double dy = *(gradient + 1); // Ouch!!!
```

Thus, from the viewpoint of maintainability, I prefer to say exactly what I mean, without obscuring the intent with context-dependent synonyms. If I mean "take i-th element of a" then I say exactly that in C++ lingo:

```
a[i];
```

rather than relying that **for the particular implementation of a** one can use a fancier expression for the same.

Comment: OP only tagged the question with C, not C++. Therefore, this answer is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

`a[i]` should be preferred, because it is more commonly used and so will be understood more quickly by the person reading the code.

Answer (score 3):

C has no operator overloading. So you are safe to use whichever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Both are equivalent. Neither one is preferred over other but `a[i]` is commonly used by programmers. `a[i] = *(a + i) = i[a]`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `a[i]` for clarity when reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned (just finished a C course), there is no difference.

Array is implemented as a pointer to the first element on the stack. So a+1 is just the address on the stack after a :)

Edit:
Also, as mentioned by John Bartholomew, even though they are the same, you might want to use a[i] instead - that is the "normal" way to do it (also in other languages) :)

Answer (score 1):

For readability purposes, I would definitely go with `a[i]`.