# Getting the value of uint8_t pointer

Tags: c

Trying to understand someone else's code. Two questions, it is redundant to cast pdata as uint8_t? And how to do I see the value of pdata?

```
void *pb; 
uint8_t *pdata  = NULL;

//re-cast pb as uint8_t type
pdata = (uint8_t*)pb; // now pdata is equal to a uint8_t of whatever pb is, pb is an empty pointer
pdata += 1000;
printf("%d\n", pdata[0]);
```

Comment: That `printf` already outputs the value pointed to by `pdata`. Is that not what you want to see?

Comment: To see the pointer value: `printf("%p\n", pdata);`

Comment: The cast is indeed redundant. C allows converting between data pointers and `void*` without casting.

Comment: Do you want to see the value of the pointer, or the value that it points to? Did you ever initialize `pb`?

Comment: Instead of `pdata += 1000`, you could just print `pdata[1000]`

Comment: Does `pb` point to an array of at least 1001 integers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why type cast a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986214/why-type-cast-a-void-pointer)

Comment: Also [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887169/is-there-a-difference-between-using-ai-and-a-i

Answer (score 1):

> Two questions, it is redundant to cast pdata as uint8_t?

Yes? The only `uint8_t*` case in your code is from `pd` pointer with is a `void*` pointer. A `void*` pointer can be implicitly converted to pointer to another type. `pdata` is a pointer to `uint8_t`, so casting it as `uint8_t*` pointer would be redundant. Casting `pdata` as `uint8_t` like `(uint8_t)pdata` would yield an implementation defined value.

> And how to do I see the value of pdata?

It's typical to cast a pointer to `void*` and then use `%p` `printf` format specifier to print the value of a pointer. Most environments I worked with just print the value of the pointer in hex then.

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)pdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting from the case when the author of the code does not know what he/she is doing such a cast (which in C is redundant) can be seen in:

1. The MISRA or another industrial standards compliant code (otherwise code analysers will cry)
2. Code which is likely to be compiled by the C++ compiler (yes I know it should not happen, but in real life someone can take your code and complain ...)